# Добавление кнопки на Toolbar. Android

Tags: android

Имеется следующий вопрос: есть активность, на нее, при нажатии кнопки меню, добавляется фрагмент. Мне необходимо, чтобы при появлении фрагмента на экране, чтобы на ToolBar добавлялась кнопка. Вопрос в том, как обратиться к ToolBar из фрагмента, если он определен в классе активности, а не фрагмента? Делать его `public` или есть какой-то другой вариант?

Comment: а почему бы просто до добавления фрагмента не добавлять кнопку на тулбар? добавлем кнопку, а потом сразу выполняем код на добавление фрагмента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый фрагмент имеет парнет Activity вы можете обратиться к данному компоненту вызвав метод ***getActivity***

Попробуйте так:

`((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Привет");`